# Presenting Login as modal iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have an app that has a login nav controller and a tab bar controller. I have set my tab bar controller to the root controller however I want the login navigation controller to display as a modal so that I can dismiss it when they're logged in and not show it at all if they are. It is reading the right line but failing to present the `landingviewcontroller`. When I run the app it jumps straight to the TabBarController.

My code is as follows:

I have a method which checks if you are logged in in my app delegate which is where I am telling it to present the landing view controller (login). I know from stepping through that it is correctly determining that I'm not logged in and going to this line of code on running:

```
[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:landingVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The full app delegate:

```
#import "GFAppDelegate.h"
#import "GFCredentialStore.h"

@implementation GFAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    UIViewController *tabBarController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    UIViewController *landingVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LandingViewController"];

    GFCredentialStore *store = [[GFCredentialStore alloc] init];

    if (store.isLoggedIn) {
        self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;
    } else {
        [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:landingVC animated:YES completion:nil];
    }


    // Set root view controller and make windows visible

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

I've tried to make this clear, but understand it's probably confusing as poorly written. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
if (store.isLoggedIn==false) {
    [tabBarController presentViewController:landingVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Great thanks. Works perfectly. Any idea how I can dismiss this in the loginViewController, do I have to import "AppDelegate" or create a new instance of the ViewController to get access to it in a separate controller.

Comment: [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; - in the loginViewController

Comment: Thanks again! sorted out that.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is to always set `rootViewController` to `tabBarController`, but if user is not logged call presentViewController from it. Something like it:

```
self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
if (!store.isLoggedIn) {
    [tabBarController presentViewController:landingVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Also works perfectly. Accepted first to answer. This works perfectly and is more concise with the !store for not. Do you have any ideas as to how I can achieve what I asked in my comment replying to the main answer? thanks for your help.

Comment: Actually my answer was first if you look at the time stamp :)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that when tries to present view controller from `self.window.rootViewController` is does not exist so `rootViewController == nil`.

I suggest you to not present it as modal (since you don't have controller to present from), but to set login view controller as root.

```
self.window.rootViewController = landingVC;
```

But if your intent was to present login above tab bar see answers suggested before mine.

Comment: Thanks, I had this setup before but I wanted to display the tab as the root as doing it this way gave me issues with the navigation controller after logging in. Thanks though. Upvoted.